# React react-sortable-hoc cancel reordering(Undo order changes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I'm using `react-sortable-hoc` to reorder table rows with Save and Cancel buttons. However, I can't find any information or example about reverting back to original order when the Cancel button is clicked after re-ordered rows.

Can't find any info or example on the [official documentation](https://clauderic.github.io/react-sortable-hoc/#/basic-configuration/basic-usage) or anywhere else. It seems weird to me that there's no cancel function built in or am I missing something?

**Edit:**
[Example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sortable-table-row-example-forked-t9jqw?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This is so we can see what it is your code is doing.

Comment: not very familiar with that module, but the way it's usually done is by storing a a deep copy of a restoration point

Comment: @DrewReese added an example code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to undo order changes then you can maintain an undo stack. Each time an order change is complete, stash a copy of the previous `data` state. When the undo button is clicked you pop from the undo stack back into the `data` state.

1. Add an `undoStack` to state.

   ```
   state = {
     data: range(1, 5).map((el) => ({
       name: `tester-${el}`,
       age: el,
       class: `Class-${el}`
     })),
     undoStack: [],
   };
   ```
2. Cache the previous `data` state in the undo stack. Here I'm using slice to keep only the last 10 revisions, but this can be tuned to fit your needs.

   ```
   _handleSort = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       data: arrayMove(prevState.data, oldIndex, newIndex),
       undoStack: [...prevState.undoStack, prevState.data].slice(-10),
     }));
   };
   ```
3. Handle undoing order changes and attach the undo handler to the button's `onClick` event handler.

   ```
   undo = () => {
     this.setState(prevState => {
       if (prevState.undoStack.length) {
         return {
           data: prevState.undoStack.pop(),
           undoStack: prevState.undoStack,
         };
       } else {
         return prevState;
       }
     })
   };

   ...

   <button type="button" onClick={this.undo}>
     Undo reorder
   </button>
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-react-sortable-hoc-cancel-reorderingundo-order-changes]

If you don't care about intermediate revisions and simply want to reset to the original order then just capture a cache of the original order and reset `data`.

```
const data = range(1, 5).map((el) => ({
  name: `tester-${el}`,
  age: el,
  class: `Class-${el}`
}));

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data,
    originalData: data, // <-- store cache of original data
    undoStack: []
  };

  ...

  <button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
      this.setState({
        data: this.state.originalData // <-- restore from cache
      });
    }}
  >
    Reset
  </button>
```

Both are implemented in the linked codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese! exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Ohsik Great! Glad this suits your needs. Cheers and good luck.